# Checking $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+1}$ for uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

I need to check this for uniform convergence

$$ f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+1} , \quad (x \in \mathbb R)$$

Here's what I did so far. (edited due to a comment telling me the way)

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R}  | f(x) - f_n(x) | = \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \; \left| \frac{x}{n+1} \right|$$
$$ g(x) = \left|\frac{x}{n+1} \right| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^2}$$
$$ g'(x) = \frac{x(n+1-x)}{(n+1)^3} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{n+1}\right)^2}} \; , \quad (x \neq 0)$$
$$ g'(x) = 0 \rightarrow x=n+1 \; , \quad (x \neq 0)$$
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R}  | f(x) - f_n(x) | = n \nless \epsilon$$

So $f_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly!
Is what I did correct?

Comment: Here is the [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can see easily that $f(x)=x$ is a pointwise limite of  $f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{n+1}$ and we have:
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{|x|}{n+1}$$
so the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent in every compact of $\mathbb{R}$ to $f$ but we have not the uniform convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ since
$$||f_n-f||_\infty=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=+\infty$$

Comment: Can you explain why the $sup$ is $+\infty$ ? Look at my edit in the question, something else turned out with me.

Comment: @TheNotMe I think that's obvious that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{1}{n+1}\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|x|=+\infty$