# why $1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt{n}|x|?$ why not $1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt{n}|x|^2?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence

Is   $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+nx^2}$ uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}?$

I found  the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378556/uniform-convergence-and-derivatives) .

Here is an outline of the solution

> $$\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-0|=\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{|1+nx^2|}=$$
> $$\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2}\leq\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{2\sqrt{n}|x|}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\overset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow }0$$
> Therefore, $\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-0|\rightarrow 0, $ i.e. $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$.

**My confusion** :  Im not getting why $1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt{n}|x|?$ why not $1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt{n}|x|^2?$

**My thinking** :  If $1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt{n}|x|^2$ then $f_n(x)$  will not uniformly convergent see   [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4217191/is-f-nx-fracx1nx2-uniformly-convergent-on-mathbbr-yes-no)

why it is a compulsory to take   $1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt{n}|x|?$

Comment: Is that a typo?  Shouldn't it be $\sup \frac {|x|}{|1+nx^2} = \sup \frac {|x|}{1+n|x|}^2 \le \sup \frac {|x|}{2\sqrt n|x|}$.

Comment: @fleablood I think you've made a typo in your comment as well.

Comment: @tmaj wouldn't surprise me... yeah.  I see it.  Hopefully it is clear my intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo.

You wrote $\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{|1+nx^2|}=\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{1+\sqrt{n}|x|^2}$

which isn't likely to be true as $|1+nx^2| = 1+nx^2 \ne 1 + \sqrt n |x|^2$.

If you replace this with $\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{|1+nx^2|}=\sup\limits_{x\in\mathbb R}\dfrac{|x|}{1+n|x|^2}$ your result will follow.

Bear in mind $1-2\sqrt n |x| +n|x|^2 = (1-\sqrt n|x|)^2 \ge 0$ so

$1+n|x|^2 \ge 2\sqrt n|x|$ (or use AM.GM) and you have your result.