# Uniform convergence of functions and intervals

Tags: uniform-convergence

We define $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+nx^2}$ for each $n\ge 1$.

I compute that $f(x):= \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x) = 0$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, I want to know in which intervals $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ the convergence is uniform.

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: Use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Comment: see the problem 5  [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math140/HW140B_4_solutions.pdf)

Comment: @user73564: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use the [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071), then the max over $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$ of the function is achieved at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and it equals $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$. So, we have

$$ \sup| f_n(x)-f(x) |= \sup \Big| \dfrac{x}{1+nx^2} \Big|= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon.$$

This shows the sequence converges uniformly over $\mathbb{R}$.

**Added:** Here is the plot of the function for $n=1,2,3$.

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me how did you plot this function?

Comment: This is great, thank you very much.

Comment: @user73564: You are very welcome.

Comment: @srijan: I used Maple. Do you want the command?

Comment: @srijan: Here is the command " plot( {x/(1+1^2*x^2),x/(1+2^2*x^2), x/(1+3^2*x^2) }, x=-6..6 );
 "

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks dear I noted down your command. :)

Comment: @srijan: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal You are welcome sir. :)

Comment: This supremum that we are calculating , this is of which set ? Set of all functions possible for all values of $n$ over the interval ? And Suppose we admit that $f_n$ is maximum for a certain value of $x$ of $n$. What does this mean ? Does this mean that at each point of the interval , the value attains its maximum value for this particular n and hence on the entire interval ? Also , in different questions , when we solve for the derivative and equate it to zero , how do we make sure that the points that we are getting lie in the Interval concerned.Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence converges uniformly on $I$ if for every $\epsilon >0, \exists N$ such that $\forall x \in I $ and $\forall n \geq N$, we have $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

For the interval $|x| \leq 1$, we see that $x(1+nx) = x +nx^2 \leq 1 + nx^2$, so that $\frac{x}{1+nx^2} \leq \frac{x}{x(1+nx)} = \frac{1}{1+nx}$.  So, to make this smaller than $\epsilon$, choose $N_1 = (\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1)$.

For the interval $|x| >1$, we have that $|\frac{x}{1+nx^2}| \leq |\frac{x}{nx^2}| =|\frac{1}{nx}| < \frac{1}{n}$.  So, choose $N_2 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Comparing $N_1, N_2$, we see that we can choose $N = N_2$.  Convergence is uniform on $\mathbb{R}$.