# Checking for uniform convergence $f_{n}(x)$ $=$ $n^{2}x\ (1-x)^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $f_{n}(x)$ $=$ $n^{2}x\ (1-x)^{n}$ with $0\le x\le 1$, where $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to the zero function $f$.

How do I check for uniform convergence?

Can someone provide me with some hints?

Comment: Say something about what you have tried.

Comment: Try this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Comment: People tend to downvote if you don't include some of your attempted work; I recommend you to put some of your work down, that way people would be more likely to help ...

Answer (score 6):

Convergence is not uniform.  $$f_n(x)=n^2x(1-x)^n$$

Let $x=n^{-1}$. Then $$f_n(n^{-1})=n\left(1-\frac 1 n\right)^n$$ is unbounded as $n\to\infty$.

Thus convergence cannot be uniform.

Answer (score 3):

Use the theorem for uniform convergence and Riemann Integrability.

Integrate each of your functions of $\{f_n\}$ in $[0,1]$ and take limit $n \rightarrow \infty$. You shall get 1. Whereas you shall get 0 after integrating the limit function.

Comment: This is a cute solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Calculate $\sup\limits_{0\leq x\leq 1}\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|$

(edit: that's literally common sense, so adding one more line)

$$\sup_{0\leq x\leq 1}|f_n(x)-f(x) |=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^n\times\frac{n^2}{n+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for the edit, what's the latex code for that "big parentheses"?

Comment: It is `\left( something \right)`