# Uniform convergence of $f_n = (n^a x^2)/(n^2 +x^3)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

My question is, if you have the sequence $$f_n = \frac{n^\alpha x^2}{n^2 +x^3}$$ on $[0, \infty)$, for values of a for $0<\alpha<2$ does the sequence uniformly converge?

I guess another way to think about it is what values can $a$ take such that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\sup_{x \in [0,\infty)}\left[\frac{n^a x^2}{n^2 +x^3}\right]\right) = 0. $$

I'm having trouble proving this.. but I think that intuitively, $\alpha$ can be less than or equal to 1.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try calculating the maximum of $f_n(x)$ explicitly.

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Answer (score 5):

If you work the problem out using the [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071), then you will find that the maximum is achieved at

> $$x=(2n^2)^{1/3}$$

and is given by

> $$ \frac{ 2^{ \frac{2}{3}} }{3} n^{ a - \frac{2}{3}}.$$

Now, you should be able to finish the problem.