# Proof of uniform convergence on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Prove that the sequence {$k_n$}$_{n=1}^\infty$, defined by $$k_n (x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}$$ for all x $\in \mathbb{R}$ and each positive integer n, converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal this method seems like it would require splitting it up into three intervals- from -infinity to the infimum, infimum to supremum, and supremum to infinity. is that the case, or is there a way to do it in one?

Answer (score 0):

Note that, you need to find the following

> $$ \sup_{-\infty<x<\infty} \Bigg| \frac{x}{1+n x^2}  - 0\Bigg|. $$

Let

> $$ g(x)= \frac{x}{1+n x^2}.$$

Using the derivative technique, the max of $g$ is achieved at $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ (by the second derivative test) and it's given by

> $$ g(1/\sqrt{n})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}} \implies \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}< \epsilon  $$