# uniform convergence of a sequence of functions.

Tags: real-analysis

The question is to check whether the sequences are uniformly convergent or not:

1. $f_n(x)=Sin^nx$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$
2. $\frac{1}{1+(x-n)^2}$  on $(-\infty.0)$
3. $\frac{1}{1+(x-n)^2}$  on $(0.\infty)$

For $(1)$

$f_n(x)\to0$. Now  $sup[f_n(x)-0]$=$1$(It never attains $1$ but it is not mandatory for the supremum to lie in the set). Hence $(1)$ doesn't converge uniformly.

For $(2)$

$f_n(x)\to0$

$\frac{1}{1+(x-n)^2}\le\frac{1}{1+n^2}\le\frac{1}{n^2}\le\epsilon$. Here $n$ bdepends only on $\epsilon$. Hence uniformly convergent.

For $(3)$

$f_n(x)\to0$

$sup[f_n(x)]=1$, which it attains at $x=n$. Hence not uniformly convergent.

Is there any better way of showing these??
By sequential criteria?

Comment: I think you should be more careful with (2)

Comment: since x<0, ultimately it turns out to be (1+y)^2 for some y=-x

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Comment: This looks good to me. I don't know if there is a simpler way to deal with these problems.