# let $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}$. determine whether $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$ and whether $f_n \to f $ uniformly on $[0, \infty)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

this sequence was given as a practice problem and I'm really having trouble. Heres  the question:

let $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{1 + x^n}$. determine whether $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$ and whether $f_n \to f $ uniformly on $[0, \infty)$

My Work: I determined that the pointwise limit $f(x) = $lim$f_n(x)$ has to be $1$ but I am not too sure what to do after this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try the [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071) in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is the pointwise limit a continuous function? Each function is continuous, so if convergence were uniform, the limit would be too.

*Ans* No, it is not. It is $0$ in $[0,1)$, $1/2$ at $1$ and $1$ over $(1,\infty]$.

Comment: the question doesnt specify. All that it says is that it is a sequence

Comment: @user3182418 I am asking *you*. Is the pointwise limit a continuous function?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills It does.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following characterization : $f_n $ converges uniformly to $f$ on $S$ iff

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in S} \{ |f_n(x) - f(x) | \} = 0$$