# Uniform Convergent question. Having trouble dealing with the $x^n$ term.

Tags: real-analysis

How would you show that $(1-x) x^n$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Is the sum of uniformly convergent functions uniformly convergent?

Comment: @abiessu Are you mixing up uniform convergence and uniform continuity? Note that $x^n$ and $-x^{n+1}$ are not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove uniform convergence, first, note that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1-x)x^n=0 $. Now, you need to prove

> $$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|(1-x)x^n-0|< \epsilon. $$

To find the $\sup$, you can use the derivative test to get that the sup is achieved at point $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$, that gives

> $$ \sup_{x\in[0,1]}|(1-x)x^n-0|= \frac{(\frac{n}{n+1})^n}{n+1}<\dots. $$

I leave it here for you to finish the problem. See related [technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).