# uniform convergence of a functional sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Is this sequence of functions 
$$f_n(x)=n^3x(1-x)^n$$ 
converges uniformly for $x\in[0,1]$. I need some help on this.

Comment: i edited the question.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pointwise $f_{n}(x_0)\rightarrow 0 $ in $[0,1]$. So in order to show that it converges uniformly you just need to show that 
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-0|\rightarrow0$$
Now take the $x-$derivative
$$f'_{n}(x)=n^3(1-x)^n-n^4x(1-x)^{n-1}=n^3(1-x)^{n-1}(1-x-nx)$$
You can easily find that the maximum point is
$$x_{max}=\frac{1}{n+1}\ ,$$
so 
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)-0|=\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f_n(x)|=|f_n(x_{max})|=n^3\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\sim \frac{n^2}{e}$$
that is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

Before asking for uniform convergence, we have to seek for pointwise convergence. If $x\in [0,1)$, then $n^3x(1-x)^n\to 0$ because $n^3a^n\to 0$ for $a\in (0,1)$.

Hence $f_n(x)\to 0$ for any $x\in [0,1]$. Since $f(1/n)=n^2(1-1/n)^n$ and $f(1/n)=(1-1/n)^n\to e^{-1}\gt 0$, $\sup_{x\in [0,1]}|f_n(x)|\to +\infty$ as $n$ goes to infinity.