# Clarifying the meaning of uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I just want to clarify the notion of uniform convergence.

Suppose, I have a sequence of function like this,

$$f_n(x) = \frac{n}{e+n^2x^2}$$

Clearly for $|x| > 0$, $f_n(x) \to 0$ if $n \to \infty$. I was tempted to say that for $|x| > 0$ the function converges uniformly to $0$. But I realize, wouldn't we have variable value for $N$ if $x < 1$?

Here's the rough argument that leads me to that conclusion: (valid only for $|x| \ge 1$)

$$\frac{n}{e+n^2x^2} < \frac{1}{nx^2} < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

Should the uniform convergence interval then only be for $|x| \ge 1$?

Does this corresponds to the definition of uniform convergence? Am I misinterpreting it? Or instead, as long as the sequence of function converges to the same function, whatever the value of $x$ is, then it is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Try to use this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370023/how-to-prove-a-sequence-of-a-function-converges-uniformly/370071#370071) and see what you get.

Comment: Wow nice technique! So the point is, we can indeed still find the maximum value of the function that doesn't depend on $x$ right? It's just my bound is not as sophisticated to account for $x < 1$?

Comment: Yes indeed It is a very useful technique and you should learn it.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence converges uniformly on any interval $[a,+\infty)$, no matter how small $a > 0$ is, but not on $(0,+\infty)$.

To show uniform convergence on $[a,+\infty)$, note that $f_n(x) \leq n/(e + n^2a^2)$ on this interval. Thus if  $b_n = \sup_{x \geq a} |f_n(x)|$, we have $b_n \leq n/(e + n^2a^2)$, hence $b_n \to 0$. This proves that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,+\infty)$.

However, for $(0,+\infty)$, note that $f_n(1/n) = n/(e + 1)$. Thus if we let $c_n = \sup_{x > 0} |f_n(x)|$, we have $c_n \geq n/(e + 1)$, so $c_n$ does not tend to zero. Therefore $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to zero on $(0,+\infty)$. (And since the sequence *does* converge pointwise to $0$, it can't converge uniformly to any other function.)

Comment: It would be great if you can make a connection between your answer and the definition of uniform convergence, especially the independence on $x$ part for $[a, +\infty]$.

Comment: I've edited the answer.